# Rounding latitude and longitude to get within approximately 500 meters

Tags: latitude-longitude

I have over 350,000 pairs of latitude and longitude decimal values. These pairs represent locations in the US. These data give me fairly precise data, but I don't need to be this precise.

I'm looking for recommendations on how to round these values so that I can reduce my locations from 350,000 to something smaller.

- Rounding both values to the nearest hundredth produces 138k pairs.
- Rounding both values to the nearest thousandth produces 320k pairs.

If rounding to the 2nd decimal, I fear that I'm reaching out too far. If rounding to the 3rd decimal, I feel like I still have too many pairs. Ideally, I would like to be within perhaps 400 to 600 meters of the actual lat/lon. I suppose rounding to the 3rd decimal is indeed approaching that desired area, but slightly on the strict side.

Has anyone tried this, and maybe taken the approach of rounding latitude to the 2nd decimal and longitude to the 3rd decimal? Would you recommend one over the other? Again, most data in the continental US, with some in Alaska and Hawaii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping the precision in your latitude values is more helpful than the precision in longitude. At the equator the precision (in degrees) comes out to the same, but as you move north or south from there, the distance in a degree longitude becomes less and less.

If you really need within the 500 meters, and you assume your rounding of each location has equal loss of distance, you can round each value by 354 meters. (That is you target rounding each an equal distance on average.)

354 meters is about 0.0033 degrees of latitude anywhere in the world. (There's less than a percent of variance in this depending on location.)

But longitude changes size much more dramatically:
In northern Alaska, at a latitude of 70 degrees N, 354 meters comes close to 0.01 degrees longitude, but in Hawaii, the same distance east-west equals 0.0033 degrees.

Instead of just rounding, could you group to nearest even thousandth for latitude? For longitude, group to nearest hundredth if latitude is greater than 50 group to nearest even thousandth otherwise.

Might be a pain to explain to people, but not too painful to code, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I appreciate it. I have decided to keep my 350k+ points due to a product request, sigh. I'm marking this as an approved answer in case things change down the road.